# Optimizing AJAX function to get SQL data from user input into a drop down menu and append to a table Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax

I have created an AJAX function that gets an input from a user and returns a match from an SQL database into a drop down box with PHP. When the user clicks on an item from the drop down it fills the box with the SQL data and fills two more boxes with other necessary data. Next, I can get the data from all boxes and put it into an interactive table using javascript. This function works most of the time but sometimes the variables lose the necessary data before the user clicks to append it to the table. It also feels like it needs some optimization so that the AJAX request isn't so resourceful. Is there any better way to pull data from the SQL database? Maybe a JSON file?

AJAX

```
//Getting value from "ajax.php".
function fill(Value) {
   $('#search').val(Value);
   $('#display').hide();

}

$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#search").keyup(function() {
       var food_name = $('#search').val();
       if (food_name == "") {
           $("#display").html("");
       }
       else {
           $.ajax({
               type: "GET",
               url: "ajax.php",
               data: {
                   search: food_name
               },
               success: function(html) {
                   $("#display").html(html).show();
               }
           });
       }
   });
});

function fill2(Value2) {
   $('#search2').val(Value2);
   $('#display2').hide();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#search2").keyup(function() {
       var food_category = $('#search2').val();
       if (food_category == "") {
           $("#display2").html("");
       }
       else {
           $.ajax({
               type: "GET",
               url: "ajax.php",
               data: {
                   search: food_category
               },
               success: function(html) {
                   $("#display2").html(html).show();
               }
           });
       }
   });
});


function fill3(Value3) {
   $('#search3').val(Value3);
   $('#display3').hide();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#search3").keyup(function() {
       var food_time = $('#search3').val();
       if (food_time == "") {
           $("#display3").html("");
       }
       else {
           $.ajax({
               type: "GET",
               url: "ajax.php",
               data: {
                   search: food_time
               },
               success: function(html) {
                   $("#display3").html(html).show();
               }
           });
       }
   });
});
```

PHP

```
        <?php

    include "config.php";

    if (isset($_GET['search'])) {
       $Name = $_GET['search'];
       $Query = "SELECT food_name, food_category, food_time FROM food WHERE food_name LIKE '%$Name%' ";
       $ExecQuery = MySQLi_query($link, $Query);
       echo '
    <ul>
       ';
       while ($Result = MySQLi_fetch_array($ExecQuery)) {
           ?>
       <li onclick='fill("<?php echo $Result['food_name']; ?>")'>
         <p  onclick='fill2("<?php echo $Result['food_category']; ?>")'>
          <p2  onclick='fill3("<?php echo $Result['food_time']; ?>")'>

       <a>
           <?php echo $Result['food_name']; ?>
            <?php echo $Result['food_category']; ?>
             <?php echo $Result['food_time']; ?>

       </li></a>
       <?php
    }}
    ?>
    </ul>
```

Comment: You have a very bad mixture here of JS and PHP. I would fist recommend to make your ajax.php just return a JSON of all the data you need for your representation(JS+HTML), and then process the data in the browser. From your code it's not clear how ajax.php functions, because it just echos 3 times( this is not not how ajax requests work)

Comment: DRY - don't repeat yourself. Use a class and get the ID from the search field to see what to look for. Use JSON and delegate the click and keyups

Comment: Pretty poor I know but it was my first time using AJAX and I gathered it was not the best way to do this with repetition. Thank you

Comment: your sql is vulnerable to sql injection - you ought to look at using `prepared statements`

Comment: Yes it will be as this is only a project for university and there is no scope for security.